# how to refresh a VF page?

Tags: salesforce

I have created a VF page for an object Merchandise,which consists of 3 fields - name,price and quantity.when ever I create a new record and click save button , new record is saved in tat object (Merchandise) but the values in the fields are not refreshed.

What has to be added to the code, which is given below:

```
public with sharing class mdetailcon {   
public Merchandise__c mer{set;get;}  
public mdetailcon(){
mer = new Merchandise__c();     
public PageReference save() {  
insert mer; 
return null;  
 }      }

<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="mdetailcon">     
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock > 
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" > 
<apex:inputField value="{!mer.name}" label="Name"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!mer.Price__c}" label="Price"/>    
<apex:inputField value="{!mer.Q__c}" label="Quantity"/>    
</apex:pageBlockSection>    
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/   
 </apex:pageBlock>  
 </apex:form>    
  </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,check the code below

```
public PageReference save() {
insert mer;
PageReference pageRef = new pageReference('/apex/merchdetail'); 

   // ('/apex/yourvfpagename',as the vfpage i have created was merchdetail)

pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;

}
```

Comment: @Tonino Tripodi ...hi can you plz check your fb.